# Single particle in proper place

Tags: particles

So. I am making a pantograph lifting animation and to achieve realism, on the moment when the pantograph touches the overhead wire I want to make a single perticle - spark but the single spark is emitted in the back of the overhead wire(see picture). How do I change particle's location?[image: The particle is in the back of overhead wire, as mentioned before.]

Comment: you can change to emit at vertices and make the vertex exactly at your needed point

Comment: Thanks, ill try.

Comment: Ok, it is emmiting from vertices but from the first one, how do I change?

Answer (score 0):

you can change to emit at vertices and make the vertex exactly at your needed point, by changing the seed value.

the other possibility: just add a single vertex at the point where you want the emitter to be and add on that vertex your particle system -> done